# Saving Inception_Resnet_v2 Features in h5py

Tags: keras, deep-learning, h5py

I am currently trying to use a number of pre-trained ImageNet networks in keras to extract features from images. To do this I am removing the top layer of the network, pre-processing the input according to each of the networks requirements and then saving the outputs in an hdf5 file. I have used several other pre-trained networks using this exact same approach and code (only switching out the network) and it seems to work perfectly. However, the network I am struggling to get to work is 'InceptionResNetV2'. I don't believe I am getting any problems with the network, only with the saving - I've attached a slightly simplified version of the code. Changing the model in the feature extractor and the model in pre-processing means it works perfectly - for vgg16, vgg19, resnet, inception etc - all good.

```
db = h5py.File(hdf5_path, mode="w")

featuresDB = db.create_dataset("features", shape=features_shape, dtype="float")

images = [cv2.imread(path, 1) for path in image_paths[start:end]]

images = inception_resnet_v2.preprocess_input(images)

features = feature_extractor.extract(images)

featuresDB[start:end] = features
```

However, this produces the following error. I have tried to change the dtype of the data going into featuresDB to an int, but that had no effect. Any suggestions appreciated!

```
File "h5py/utils.pyx", line 101, in h5py.utils.convert_tuple
TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Extract_Features.py", line 111, in <module>
    extract_features(image_paths, hdf5_path=args["features_db"], 
feature_extractor=feature_extractor)

File "Extract_Features.py", line 83, in extract_features
    featuresDB = db.create_dataset("features", shape=features_shape, dtype="float")

File "/home/will/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py", line 
106, in create_dataset
    dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(self, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)

File "/home/will/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 137, in make_new_dset
    sid = h5s.create_simple(shape, maxshape)

File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

File "h5py/h5s.pyx", line 95, in h5py.h5s.create_simple

File "h5py/utils.pyx", line 103, in h5py.utils.convert_tuple
TypeError: Can't convert element 1 (None) to hsize_t
```

Comment: Looks like it's have problems with the `features_shape` variable.  The error occurs in that initial `create_dataset`.  Either tha variable isn't a tuple, or has some bad values - not integers.  I think `h5py` allows one `None` in the shape to indicate a growth axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [201]: f = h5py.File('test.h5','w')
```

I can recreate your error with this expression:

```
In [203]: ds = f.create_dataset('features', shape=(None,3), dtype=float)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
h5py/utils.pyx in h5py.utils.convert_tuple()

TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-203-a5733d841c5c> in <module>()
----> 1 ds = f.create_dataset('features', shape=(None,3), dtype=float)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py in create_dataset(self, name, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)
    104         """
    105         with phil:
--> 106             dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(self, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)
    107             dset = dataset.Dataset(dsid)
    108             if name is not None:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py in make_new_dset(parent, shape, dtype, data, chunks, compression, shuffle, fletcher32, maxshape, compression_opts, fillvalue, scaleoffset, track_times)
    135         sid = h5s.create(h5s.NULL)
    136     else:
--> 137         sid = h5s.create_simple(shape, maxshape)
    138 
    139 

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/h5s.pyx in h5py.h5s.create_simple()

h5py/utils.pyx in h5py.utils.convert_tuple()

TypeError: Can't convert element 0 (None) to hsize_t
```

A `None` is ok in the `maxshape` parameter, but not the `shape` - this is for a resizeable dataset:

```
In [204]: ds = f.create_dataset('features', shape=(10,3), maxshape=(None,3), dty
     ...: pe=float)
In [205]: ds
Out[205]: <HDF5 dataset "features": shape (10, 3), type "<f8">
In [206]: ds.resize((20,3))
In [207]: ds
Out[207]: <HDF5 dataset "features": shape (20, 3), type "<f8">
```

I haven't used `keras`, but from other SO questions, and documentation, `None` is allowed in its `shape`.  `None` is not allowed in `numpy` array shape.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your reply! You were right - there is indeed a problem with the features shape variable - it includes 'none' variables, although this is derived from the output shape of the 'InceptionResNetV2' which I think I'll ask a different question about